# Datatable sobrepasa a su elemento padre en tamaño de altura

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind

Tengo un datatable dentro de un div, el div tiene una altura máxima, y el datatable tiene la clase de tailwind h-full para que tome el tamaño del elemento padre, pero aún así el datatable sobrepasa al componente padre cuando las filas sobrepasan al alto del componente que lo contiene.

Este es el código de HomeView que renderiza el CardComponent

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { CardComponent, TabComponent, DatatableComponent } from '../../components';

export const HomeView = ():JSX.Element => {

  const [ modalState ] = useState<boolean>(false);

  const [actualTab, setActualTab] = useState<string>('pagos-pendientes');

  const PENDING_PAYMENTS_COLUMNS = ['Alumno', 'Servicio', 'Periodo', 'Monto Bs', 'Monto $'];

  const HISTORIC_PAYMENTS_COLUMNS = ['Alumno', 'Servicio', 'Periodo', 'Monto Bs', 'Monto $'];

  const handleTabChange = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement>, value: string) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setActualTab(value);
  }

  return (
    <div className='px-10 flex items-center flex-col'>
      <div className='w-full flex justify-center gap-3 md:gap-x-20'>
        <div onClick={(e) => {handleTabChange(e, 'pagos-pendientes')}}>
          <TabComponent text='Pagos pendientes' isActive={actualTab === 'pagos-pendientes'} />
        </div>
        <div onClick={(e) => {handleTabChange(e, 'pagos-historicos')}}>
          <TabComponent text='Histórico de pagos' isActive={actualTab === 'pagos-historicos'}/>
        </div>
      </div>
      <CardComponent className={`${modalState ? 'hidden' : ''} w-full mt-5 h-full`}>
      {
        actualTab === 'pagos-pendientes' ?
        <DatatableComponent columns={PENDING_PAYMENTS_COLUMNS} className='h-full'/> :
        <DatatableComponent columns={HISTORIC_PAYMENTS_COLUMNS} className='h-full'/>
      }
      </CardComponent>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Este es el código de mi CardComponent

```
import { ReactNode } from "react";

interface ICardProps {
  children: ReactNode;
  className: string;
}

export const CardComponent = ({ children, className }: ICardProps):JSX.Element => {

  return (
    <div className={`bg-white px-4 py-8 shadow-2xl rounded-lg ${className} max-w-5xl max-h-44`}>
    {
      children
    }
    </div>
  );
}
```

Este es el código de mi datatable

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { useCounter } from "../../hooks";
import { PaginatorComponent } from "../paginator/paginator.component";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { RootState } from "../../store";
import { ModalComponent } from "../modals/modal.component";
import { DetailPaymentComponent } from "..";

interface IDatatableProps {
  columns: string[];
  key?: string;
  className?: string;
  activePagination?: boolean;
  useQuery?: any;
  modal?: JSX.Element;
  modalChild?:JSX.Element;
  onClick?: (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLTableRowElement>) => void;
}

export const DatatableComponent = (props: IDatatableProps):JSX.Element => {

  const {columns, key, className, onClick, useQuery, activePagination, modal, modalChild} = props;

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const [activeModal, setActiveModal] = useState<boolean>(false);

  const {counter, handleDecrement, handleIncrement} = useCounter({initialValue: 1});

  const { debts } = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.debts);

  // const [data, {}] = useQuery(counter);

  const data = debts;

  const handleRowClick = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLTableRowElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const index = e.currentTarget.getAttribute('id');
    // dispatch(SetPaymentDetail({

    // }));
    setActiveModal(true);
  }

  const HEADER_CELLS_STYLE = `text-center`

  const ROWS_STYLE = `grid grid-cols-${columns.length} cursor-pointer text-center`

  const CELLS_STYLE = 'my-auto';

  const getSingleData = (obj: Object):string[] => {
    return Object.values(obj);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <table className={`hidden ${!activePagination ? 'overflow-auto' : ''} md:grid grid-rows-${data.length + 1} gap-4`}>
        <tr className={ROWS_STYLE}>
        {
          columns.map((column: string, index: number) => (
            <th className={`${HEADER_CELLS_STYLE}`} key={index}>{column}</th>
          ))
        }
        </tr>
        {
          data.map((element: Object, index: number) => (
            <tr className={ROWS_STYLE} onClick={handleRowClick} id={index.toString()}>
            {
              getSingleData(element).map((prop) => (
                <td className={`${CELLS_STYLE}`}>
                  {prop}
                </td>
              ))
            }
            </tr>
          ))
        }
      </table>
      {
        activeModal && <ModalComponent
                          handleClose={() => setActiveModal(false)}
                          title="Detalle de pago"
                          bodyElement={<DetailPaymentComponent />}
                        />
      }
      {
        activePagination === true ?
          <PaginatorComponent
            className=''
            counter={counter}
            handleDecrement={handleDecrement}
            handleIncrement={handleIncrement}
          />
          : null
      }
    </>
  );
}
```